# How do i import this project?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

Hi I have found this github project:
https://github.com/ManuelPeinado/FadingActionBar

I have tried to import "samples-stock" and "library" into eclipse. Then I assign "library" as a library and add it in "samples-stock".

How would you make it work? I dont understand the authors instructions:

The library is pushed to Maven Central as a AAR, so you just need to add the following dependency to your build.gradle.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Does your project, in which you want to use this lib, uses Gradle as build system?
If so, add dependency to build.gradle, as author suggests:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.manuelpeinado.fadingactionbar:fadingactionbar:3.1.2'
}
```

Else, I believe Android Studio is Intellij IDEA Community Edition, just with android plugin, thus you should be able to add dependency from "Maven" in Libraries. Just copy & paste the

```
"com.github.manuelpeinado.fadingactionbar:fadingactionbar:3.1.2"
```

line to the window which opens.

Comment: I would like to import his sample project, do you know how I can do it in eclipse or android studio?(What does it mean to compile in dependencies?)

Comment: In Android Studio with gradle plugin enabled, you should be able to 'import project'-and then pin it to build.gradle.

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse:

File->Import->Existing android code into workspace and import library from disk drive.

If you want to run samples that are present in that library you can run them as "Android Application", like any other project.

If you want to use it in your project:

Right click on your project -> Properties -> Android -> Add(select that library) and you are good to go.